# SQL query with multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I want to write a query which will join 2 tables. Will take all vales from Table1, join with Table2. But, it Query column 'Language' should be also populated.

In example below - there should be as many rows for ID 3, as many distinct languages in column 'Language' in Table2. So here we have E, F but when Table2 will be filled with more languages, those ID's from Table1 which do not have names should be in Query result with all of them.
How to achieve this?:)

Table1:

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Table 2:

| ID | Name | Language |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | E |
| 1 | b | F |
| 2 | c | E |
| 2 | d | F |

Result Query:

| ID | Name | Language |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | E |
| 1 | b | F |
| 2 | c | E |
| 2 | d | F |
| 3 | NULL | E |
| 3 | NULL | F |

Comment: `there should be as many rows for ID 3` Can you please clarify ?

Comment: Are you looking something like this : https://dbfiddle.uk/OG7dSk9M

Comment: @Tushar in Result Query in my example, for ID = 3 there are 2 rows with E and F in Language column because in Table 2 in Language there is only E and F. If we add ID=4 with Languages E, F, G, Query should show for ID=3 3 rows with E, F and G.

Comment: Well, You have answer now; and it matches your expected output :) Please make sure to accept it if it has solved your problem

Comment: You have a mssing table here `Language` which should contain a list of languages. Then you can just do the cross join with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `CROSS JOIN` all available languages and get so all combinations for an ID, finally you `LEFT JOIN` the name

```
SELECT
t1.[ID],t2.[Name], t3.[Language] 
FROM table1 t1
  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT [Language] FROM table2) t3
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.[ID] = t2.[ID] AND t2.[Language] = t3.[Language]
ORDEr BY t1.[ID],t2.[Name], t3.[Language]
```

| ID | Name | Language |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | E |
| 1 | b | F |
| 2 | c | E |
| 2 | d | F |
| 3 | *null* | E |
| 3 | *null* | F |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xGpxORAH)

Comment: Thise brackets are hurting my eyes.

Comment: i escape all columns, if anyone, has other columns and they use reserved words